# QVBoxLayout: How to vertically align widgets to the top instead of the center

Tags: qt, qlayout

In Qt, When I add widgets to my layout, they are vertically centered by default. Is there a way to "List" the widgets from top to bottom instead of centering them vertically?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

use `void QLayout::setAlignment ( Qt::Alignment alignment )` method to set alignment according to your choice.

Comment: I don't think this gives enough information. For a start there is no such method: it is (in PyQt5) `setAlignment(QWidget *w, Qt::Alignment alignment)` and `setAlignment(QLayout *l, Qt::Alignment alignment)`, and my first experiments seem to show that using either of these methods on a `QVBoxLayout` does not simply enable its added components to be aligned neatly to the top ...

Answer (score 59):

If you have a `QVBoxLayout` and want your fixed size widgets to be stacked at the top, you can simply append a vertical stretch at the end:

```
layout.addStretch()
```

If you have multiple stretchers or other stretch items, you can specify an integer stretch factor argument that defines their size ratio.

See also [addStretch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) and [addSpacerItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addSpacerItem).

Add two `layout.addStretch()` before and after adding the widgets to center them vertically:

```
    layout.addStretch()
    layout.addWidget(self.message)
    layout.addWidget(self.userid_field)
    layout.addWidget(self.password_field)
    layout.addWidget(self.loginButton)
    layout.addStretch()
```

Not sure whether this answers your original question, but it is the answer to the one that I had when googling and being led to this page - so it might be useful for others too.

Comment: I used to be a fan of this method, but I just realized that `layout.setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop)` provides a better behavior than `layout.addStretch()` when a top-aligned layout has top-aligned child layouts. Using addStretch(), the available space will be equally distributed between parent and child spacers: `[[h1--][h2--]--]`. Using setAlignment(), the space is given in priority to the parent: `[[h1][h2]------]`, keeping the height of the children to their preferred height h1 and h2. I think the latter is often a more desired behavior, although the former may definitely have use cases.

Comment: @BorisDalstein Strange... my experience is if anything the opposite to what you describe.

Comment: In the QtCreator, this is called Vertical Spacer (or Horizontal Spacer), and their icons are a spring, if someone is trying to do this in the graphical interface.

Answer (score 33):

I find this a little more complicated than just using `layout.setAlignment()`.  It kept not working for me until just now, when I figured out that if you have expanding widgets that you set a maximum height for, then that widget will not be aligned the way you want.

Here is example code that does *not* top align the `QTextBrowser()` widget even though I call `layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)`.  Sorry that it is in Python, but it is pretty easy to translate to C++ (I have gone the other way many times).

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    """
    Create a widget that aligns its contents to the top.
    """
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        label = QLabel('label:')
        layout.addWidget(label)

        info = QTextBrowser(self)
        info.setMinimumHeight(100)
        info.setMaximumHeight(200)
        layout.addWidget(info)        
        # Uncomment the next line to get this to align top.
#         layout.setAlignment(info, Qt.AlignTop)
        
        # Create a progress bar layout.
        button = QPushButton('Button 1')        
        layout.addWidget(button)        

        # This will align all the widgets to the top except
        # for the QTextBrowser() since it has a maximum size set.
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    widget.resize(QSize(900, 400))
    
    app.exec_()
```

The following explicitly calls `layout.setAlignment(info, Qt.AlignTop)` to get the expanding text widget to work.

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    """
    Create a widget that aligns its contents to the top.
    """
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        label = QLabel('label:')
        layout.addWidget(label)

        info = QTextBrowser(self)
        info.setMinimumHeight(100)
        info.setMaximumHeight(200)
        layout.addWidget(info)        
        # Uncomment the next line to get this to align top.
        layout.setAlignment(info, Qt.AlignTop)
        
        # Create a progress bar layout.
        button = QPushButton('Button 1')        
        layout.addWidget(button)        

        # This will align all the widgets to the top except
        # for the QTextBrowser() since it has a maximum size set.
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    widget.resize(QSize(900, 400))
    
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: In PyQt6, AlignTop will be found under Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop: layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop) should be layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)

Answer (score 10):

After comparison between the two solutions, it seems that :

```
myLayout.setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop)
```

works for several widget alignement but :

```
myLayout.setAlignment(myWidget, Qt::AlignTop)
```

works only for the first widget you add to the layout.
After all, the solution depends also to the QSizePolicy of yours widgets.

Comment: Was this by any chance PyQt4? In PyQt5 there is no `QLayout` method `setAlignment` with one parameter: only the second solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using QT creator, you just add a "Vertical Spacers" at the bottom of your widget.

Answer (score 0):

In pyQt (and PySide) we have Qt.AlignCenter (align on main direction), Qt.AlignHCenter (align on horizontal direction), Qt.AlignVCenter (align on vertical direction), use one of it when you need it.