# How can I center a label in the center of a QWizardPage?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, wizard

I have a label:

```
self.label = QtLabel(self)
```

that is inside of a VBoxLayout.

That I want to set in the center of a QWizardPage, no matter what size the window becomes. I managed to get it centered horizontally with:

```
self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

but I cannot seem to get it to center vertically too. I've tried

```
self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

and:

```
self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | AlignVCenter)
```

and a couple of other things that I cannot remember at this moment (I'll edit if I do). After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14899976/1727263) it seemed the problem had something to do with setting a min and max size. I tried that, setting MinimumHeight and MaximumHeight to `200`. That roughly centered the label but it doesn't adapt to changes in the window's height, only its width.

How can I center this label directly in the middle of my page?

Comment: Is the label the only widget inside your VBoxLayout?

Comment: @LahiruChandima Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your label in between two spacer items. Your vertical layout should also be laid out in its parent widget so it takes full size of the parent.

```
QSpacerItem* verticalSpacer1 = new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
label = new QLabel(Form);
label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
QSpacerItem* verticalSpacer2 = new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer1);
verticalLayout->addWidget(label);
verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set a minimum size policy you could use QWidgets to do something like this:

```
QWizardPage.__init__(self)

    intro_text = "Some text that needs to be centered..."

    self.introVBox = QVBoxLayout(self)

    self.sizer_top = QWidget()
    self.sizer_top.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    self.sizer_bottom = QWidget()
    self.sizer_bottom.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    self.label = QLabel(self)
    self.label.setText(intro_text)
    self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.introVBox.addWidget(self.sizer_top)
    self.introVBox.addWidget(self.label)
    self.introVBox.addWidget(self.sizer_bottom)
    self.setLayout(self.introVBox);
```