# QVBoxLayout: How to align widgets to the top using Qt designer

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

I'm using qt designer only for ui layout

This is almost the same question as this one : [QVBoxLayout: How to vertically align widgets to the top instead of the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082299/qvboxlayout-how-to-vertically-align-widgets-to-the-top-instead-of-the-center)

but i'm interested on how to do that in qt designer. I don't see any option in QVBoxLayout for that top alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right-click the relevant widget and select Layout alignment > Top.

(NB: the new alignment will only be shown in preview mode).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. to add to the answer, to preview it without starting application (you just want to preview that one .ui file) you can click on Tools>Form Editor>Preview...

Comment: What if the thing you want to top-align is another layout, inside the outer layout?  I.e., I have a vertical layout, inside it is a grid layout, and I want the grid layout to be top-aligned inside the vertical layout?  Or alternatively, if you want to get rid of the vertical layout since it has only one thing inside it: I have a horizontal layout containing several things, one of which is a grid layout; how can I top-align the grid layout within the horizontal layout?

Comment: @bhaller Put the grid inside a container widget.

Comment: @ekhumoro, it took me some head-scratching but I got there.  :->  I made a QFrame container widget, using a grid top-level-layout, and put the contents of the old grid layout into that; so the grid layout itself ceased to exist.  That is working well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but solved it a different way, it even shows up on-screen:

Add whatever controls you want to the QVBoxLayout, then at the end add a Spacer (verticalSpacer), this pushes everything to the top, or you can add the verticalSpacer first to push everything down.