# Cannot align items to top in scroll area Qt

Tags: qt, alignment, qscrollarea

In a Qt Widget Application, I'm trying to make the following:

[image: Example]

My aim is to have a form with a scrollArea with a vertical layout **and each item in the scroll area aligned at the top.**

Unfortunately, it's only staying in the centre shown here:

[image: Incorrect, should be at the top]

I've tried selecting the scrollArea and chaninging vertical alignment from AlignVCenter to AlignTop, but this seems to have no effect.

[image: Alignment]

How can I align all the content to the top of the scroll box?

Comment: Give a try to [QtreeView](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html) , [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html)

Comment: The treeview/widget doesn't allow you to put in buttons or any elements inside it

Comment: hmm .. how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283677/to-set-widgets-on-children-items-on-qtreeview)

Comment: maybe, I tried but it doesn't seem to be what I want, I'm looking more for just a container with a scroll bar (scrollArea) with no columns or rows

Comment: [This image](https://gyazo.com/bcfd1014922d3f5cdff292594389bd8e) shows pretty much what I want, it has a scroll box with multiple items (recent projects) and the items start from the top

Comment: That should be done by tree model .. there are Qt examples on this in your IDE Qt Creater examples .. check them

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `QListWidget` to hold a list of not only just text, but also `QWidget`'s *(such as push buttons, line edits, etc)*.

Simply add a `QListWidget` to your window, and in C++ add the widgets to the `QListWidget` as needed.

Here are some steps to insert a button into your `QListWidget`:

Create a QListWidget item into your application.

[image: ss]

change `selectionMode` = `NoSelection` and `focusPolocy` = `NoFocus`

[image]

[image]

Put the following C++ code into your application:

```
// Create list item
QListWidgetItem *listWidgetItem = new QListWidgetItem();

// Create widget
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
verticalLayout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
widget->setLayout(verticalLayout);

// Add button to widget layout
QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton("Button!");
verticalLayout->addWidget(pushButton);

// Add list item to ul->listWidget
listWidgetItem->setSizeHint(widget->sizeHint()); // Set the size of the list item to the same as the widget
ui->listWidget->addItem(listWidgetItem);
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(listWidgetItem, widget);
```

---

**Old answer:**

*I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500439/4988637) but I will re-post it for anyone else interested.*

To align elements at the top of a scroll area, add a vertical layout as a child to the scroll area and put all your elements inside that vertical layout. *Like so:*

[image: Screenshot]

In your C++, add a [spacer item](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qspaceritem.html) to your vertical layout inside the scroll area by using [`addStretch()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addStretch):

```
ui->verticalLayout->addStretch();
```

All the items should now magically be aligned to the top.

**Edit:**

This seems to only work for the very first item, and all other items are not pushed up to the top.